# Why the call to the parent constructor is not the first call in the compiler generated constructor for Inner class?

Tags: java, inner-classes, jls, javap

Consider the following `Test` class  to demonstrate the inner class behavior in Java. The main code is in the `run` method. Rest is just plumbing code.

```
 public class Test {

        private static Test instance = null;

        private Test() {
        }

        private void run() {
            new Sub().foo();  
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            instance = new Test();
            instance.run();
        }

        class Super {
            protected void foo() {
                System.out.println("Test$Super.Foo");
            }
        }

        class Sub extends Super {
            public void foo() {
                System.out.println("Test$Sub.Foo");
                super.foo();
            }
        }
    }
```

I am just printing below the javap output for the hidden `Sub` constructor:

```
so.Test$Sub(so.Test);
    Code:
       0: aload_0       
       1: aload_1       
       2: putfield      #1                  // Field this$0:Lso/Test;
       5: aload_0       
       6: aload_1       
       7: invokespecial #2                  // Method so/Test$Super."<init>":(Lso/Test;)V
  10: return
```

Normally the compiler ensures that  the sub-class constructor would call into the super-class constructor first before going on to initialize its own fields. This aids in a correctly constructed object but I am seeing an aberration from the normative behavior in the case of  the constructor that the compiler generates for an Inner class. Why so? Is it specified by JLS?

P.S: I know that the inner class contains a hidden reference to the outer class and that reference is being set here in the above javap output. But the question is why it is set before calling super constructor. What am I missing?

Comment: The enclosing instance is, by specification, reachable from the superclass constructor.

Answer (score 1):

An inner class is an abstraction that should be as transparent to a Java programmer as possible. Consider the following class structure and think about what would happen if you set the `$this` field only after calling the inner class's super constructor.

```
class Foo {
  Foo() { System.out.println(foo()); }

  String foo() { return "foo"; }
}

class Bar {
  String bar() { return "bar"; }

  class Qux extends Foo {
    @Override 
    String foo() { return bar(); }
  }
}
```

Note how the overridden method in class `Qux` calls a method of its outer class `Bar`. For this to work, the `$this` field that holds the `Bar` instance must be set before the super constructor of `Foo` is invoked. Otherwise, you would end up with a `NullPointerException` as the field is not yet initialized. To make this more clear, look at the following call chain of any instanciation of a `Qux` instance:

```
Qux() -> Foo() -> this.foo() -> $this.bar()
```

As a programmer that is not to familiar with the implementation of an inner class, you would wonder where this exception comes from. In order to make the inner class abstraction transparent, you *must* set the field first, otherwise you would be stuck with a quite [leaky abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaky_abstraction). I do not argue that this makes the above example a good implementation, but it is legal.

Comment: Calling overridable methods from the constructor can always result in seeing uninitialized fields, this is not specific to inner classes.

Comment: Yes, but it is explicitly allowed for inner classes. But as I stated in my answer, it should be avoided nevertheless. It's normally a sign of poor design.

Comment: Calling overridable methods is always allowed, just broken. I have just read 8.8.7.1, but I still don't see what you mean. It would be highly beneficial to the quality of your answer if you actually *quoted* the JLS statement which makes the setting of the enclosing instance mandatory before the super call.

Comment: I realized that I put some meaning into the section that was not there. I can actually not find a corresponding note in the JLS.